# Apache HttpClient 4.2.5 cyrillic post

Tags: apache, encoding, utf-8, httpclient, cyrillic

I am trying to make a POST request which sends cyrillic characters to a server. The problem is that on the page there are strange characters  displayed. Here is the code I am using:

```
post = PostRequest.getInstance(url, ref, 0, ua);

List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("details", "детали"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

And then I send the request. I expect on website that the received text to be "детали", but there are strange characters.

Do you have any idea why is this happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible that the server isn't expected UTF-8 encoded data. Which server? Does making the same request through a browser work?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I had to use "windows-1251" encoding.